# Verify a transaction response correctness

Tags: transactions, security, ethers.js, data-validity

In my dapp users are sending transaction to my db, but a malicious user could just generate thousands of fake `TransactionResponse` and send them to the db, forcing me to check all of them to know if they are "real" or not.

**Is there a way to immediately discard bad transaction responses?**

Maybe using the hash and the signature? Or any other possible idea?

Note: `TransactionResponse` looks like [this](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/providers/provider/-%23-Provider-getTransaction).

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "real or not" ?
If you want to only index finalized transactions, you may emit an `Event` if some conditions are met in your contract, and use the `getLogs()` function to query them from the blockchain: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getLogs

Comment: Seems like a good way, but I also want to track failed transactions.
Basically on the frontend each time a tx is triggered I send the TransactionResponse object to the db. Then I'll check if the tx went well or not after some time. A malicious user though can send fake transaction responses and spam my db. That is what I want to avoid.